# How do I increase the size of the text or the headline in beamer, LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations

Is it possible to make the text bigger there? I mean, where "how" and "to increase" are written. I can't find anything about it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgf}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\useinnertheme{circles}  
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}   
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\section{AAA}
\subsection{BBB}
\begin{frame}{CCC}
DDD 
\[EEE\]
FFF
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: The resulf of @Bejnamin answer]

[image]

Comment: Probably you have to change the source code in your `.tex` file rather than the output. Generally, I find that a more productive strategy in the long run.

Comment: @cfr I wasn't going to change the output. I wanted to know how to change the source code....

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see the source code in your question.

Comment: @cfr Do I really need to show the source code? I just don't know the right commands to change the size of these things. I don't need anything to correct

Comment: All (OK, almost all) questions should include a Minimal Working Example. Yes. You want to change the source code. How can anybody tell you what to change without knowing what you use to produce that output? It isn't even as if you are using default settings, though an MWE would still help people to help you in that case. I have no idea how to produce the output you've shown and I'm not going to spend time researching that when you could just tell me if you really wanted help.  I know the need for MWEs has been pointed out before so, when I see this, I think you're not interested in answers.

Comment: @cfr Does it make the difference now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the outer theme smoothbars. In there, the subsection beamercolorbox height is set independently of the `subsection in head/foot` font size. So you should redefine the `headline` beamertemplate. Like this for example.

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother
```

I also adjusted the height parameter of the `beamercolorbox` to get a better vertically centered text.

Once you have done that you can easily set the font size of `subsection in head/foot` and the height of the `beamercolorbox` will adjust accordingly.

```
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\Large}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I got the strange result (see in the first post). What is it?

Comment: You have to place my code after you have loaded all themes and before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Oh, gosh, thank you so much. Sorry, I'm so stupid right now, cause I was sleeping only 2 hours today cause I needed to prepare my course work. Now I've passed it and can't think well. Shortly, your code works. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. If my answer solves your question please mark it as the solution.